# Why is my unitary matrix using linear algebra not matching the 'get_unitary' simulation?

Tags: programming, qiskit, quantum-gate, unitarity

I am using jupyter notebook and qiskit. I have a simple quantum circuit and I want to know how to get the unitary matrix of the circuit without using 'get_unitary' from the Aer unitary_simulator.
i.e.: By just using matrix manipulation, how do I get the unitary matrix of the circuit below by just using numpy and normal matrix properties?

[image]

## This is the code I am using:

```
import numpy as np

swapcnot = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0]])

cnot = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0]])

layer1 = np.kron(np.eye(2),swapcnot)

layer2 = np.kron(swapcnot, np.eye(2))

layer3 = np.kron(np.eye(2), cnot )

print(layer3@layer2@layer1)
```

## The result I should be getting:

```
[[1.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j]
 [0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 1.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j]
 [0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 1.+0.j 0.+0.j]
 [0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 1.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j]
 [0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 1.+0.j]
 [0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 1.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j]
 [0.+0.j 1.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j]
 [0.+0.j 0.+0.j 1.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j]]
```

## The actual result I am getting:

```
[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to realize that

[image]

This is also known as the Bridge gate.  This means that

[image]

From here, you can now write down the following:

```
swapcnot = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0]])

cnot = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0]])

layer1 = np.kron(np.eye(2),swapcnot)

layer2 = np.kron(swapcnot, np.eye(2))

### Bridge Gate part of the circuit ####

layer3 = np.kron(np.eye(2), cnot )

layer4 = np.kron(cnot, np.eye(2) )

layer5 = np.kron(np.eye(2), cnot )

layer6 = np.kron(cnot, np.eye(2) )

####################################

print(layer6@layer5@layer4@layer3@layer2@layer1)
```

This will output:

```
[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

which is what you expected.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you very much for the explanation!